# Unable to scroll navigation view with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-navigationview

I am unable to scroll to last rows of navigation view while doing instrumention testing with Espresso. Tried steps like:
onView(withText("Community Guidelines")).perform(scrollto(), click());

Is there a way out to perform scroll?

Comment: you can perform `scrollTo()` only for "scrollable" items (`ListView`, `ScrollView`, etc.). `NavigationView` extends `FrameLayout`, so scrolling is not working...

Comment: If your NavigationView does not contain any scrollable like LinearLayout, then you can use `NavigationViewActions.navigateto(R.id.MenuItemID)` . But if it contains the scrollable then you can give an ID to that scrollable, and then perform `swipeup()` on that scrollable using `onView(withId(R.id.scrollableID)).perform(swipeUp())` upvote the comment if it helps.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform "swipeUp" on navigation view:

```
onView(isAssignableFrom(NavigationView.class)).perform(swipeUp());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the line of code below, it worked for me.

```
onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).perform(swipeUp());
```